# how to open file in windows with python?

Tags: python, windows, path, os.path

I'm passing the file name trough sys.argv with slashes not backslashes . I'm using os.path.normpath and os.path.join but when trying to open the file I get an exception no such file or directory: and the path is with double backslashes. I'm searching for the solution for hours but nothing works.

I'v tried every tutorial I could find on google and I just keep getting the same problem. I just keep getting double back slashes. I've tried also just hardcoding the path like in example.

```
filepath = os.path.normpath(os.path.join('D:/dir1/dir2/dir3', 'myfile.txt'))
try:
    my_file = open(filepath, 'w+')
except Exception as e:
    print('Cannot create/open file w+!\n{}'.format(e))
```

I've need to be able to open the file.

Comment: can you try just:     with open('D:/dir1/dir2/dir3/myfile.txt', 'w') as write_file: foo()

Comment: Beware, all the folders in the path must exist for open to succeed...

Comment: Don't do >> os.path.join('D:/dir1/dir2/dir3', 'myfile.txt')
DO>> os.path.join('D:', 'dir1', 'dir2','dir3','myfile.txt') Using this hardcode value is not good practice

Comment: yeah after 2 hours of trying and failing and then starting to use slashes and then normalize I didn't had the correct path when I replaced the backslashet with slashes. After now checking again it works with normpath and join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python scripts it works with:

```
file_path =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.ini')
```

But if I need to build a program with py2exe the `__file__` doesn't work and I use:

```
file_path =  os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])), 'config.ini')
```

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to keep my files in a structured format where my main script will be in the root folder. This approach becomes more generic in a sense that if you try to run the same content on some other system with the different operating system, the path will raise issues.

Example

```
Project
  |-- main.py
  |-- files
       |--file1.txt
       |--file2.txt
```

Then you can simply access files by

```
with open("files/file1.txt", 'w+') as file_object:
    content = file_object.readlines() # Whatever the method
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work for me because I build a exe with py2exe and then I'm executing this exe with a DB trigger EXEC master..xp_cmdshell so the working dir is not the same as the programs. Else I wouldn't use fixed paths, but absulute paths like you.

Answer (score 0):

Add r before the file path for windows.

```
guests = open(r"C:\folder\guests.txt","w")
initial_guests = ["Bob", "Andrea", "Manuel", "Polly", "Khalid"]

for i in initial_guests:
    guests.write(i + "\n")
    
guests.close()
```